# Host an asp.net web application in IIS

Tags: asp.net

I have a query while hosting my web application in IIS:

```
* whether we need .net framework to be installed in the hosting machine with IIS?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHort answer - yes, you need the .NET Framework installed.  A .NET application won't run without the Framework.

You'll also want to make sure you set the correct framework for the web application under the ASP.NET tab, depending on what version the application was written in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as the .NET framework is what allows a .NET application to be utilized.  Here is a complete guide from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx